# NestJS async functions in a for loop

Tags: nestjs

my idea is to create a microservice that:

A- Reads everything from a collection
B- Does a loop with all that data
C- Inside the loop, each time calls another collection to get reference data from each item

ex:

```
  @Cron('*/10 * * * * *')
  async runEvery10Seconds() {

    console.log("log 1");
    let allDataFromCollection= await this.findAllData();
    for (let i = 0; i != allDataFromCollection.length; i++) {
       let item1Id = this.referencedb(allDataFromCollection[i].item1value);
       let item2Id = this.referencedb(allDataFromCollection[i].item2value);
       let item3Id = this.referencedb(allDataFromCollection[i].item3value);

  

// then I create a JSON with this new data

let data = {
item1 = item1Id ,
item2 = item2Id,
item3 = item3Id
}

this.sendHttpPost(data);
 }//close for
}
```

Things never reach the HttpPost and the only output is the first console log ("log 1") in loop, until the code terminates with

````
 5: 00007FF7428063BD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF7426B084C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF7426BBB8A v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF7426B8D39 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF7426AD961 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
10: 00007FF7426ABB65 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1317
11: 00007FF7426C5E06 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+166```
````

Comment: Could you show what `this.referencedb` does? It looks like that's _probably_ where a memory leak is happening

Comment: its just 

async referencedb (search) {
    let item = await this.refdb.findOne({ value: search });
    return item;
  }

Comment: IS it best to change the design from @cron service into a event emit ?